# how to build maximumquery in extbase

Tags: sql, typo3, extbase

referencing to that documentation https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html i want to build an maxquery to get the highest sum from a record out of a table.

**LIKE here:**

```
name  | job       | department | salary
john  | salesmen  | sales      | 2000
max   | mechanic  | workshop   | 1600
nicky | secretair | assistence | 1800
```

**AS Output:**

```
John with an salary of 2000 earns the most.
```

Comment: thought something like `$query->matching($query->equals('parameter.maximumValue', 'salary'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about ordering the values from highest to lowest and get only the first row?

Comment: sure that´s solves, to get workin it... but thought there is an directway like max() in mysql

Answer (score 0):

In Doctrine (v8+) and in the repositories you can still make plain queries like(Repository example):

```
  $query = $this->createQuery();
  //here you can use max as well
  $query->statement(
  '
     SELECT * FROM tx_sjroffers_domain_model_offer
     WHERE title LIKE ? AND organization IN ?', array('%climbing%', array(33,47))
  '
    );

  //true give us a raw result back otherwise we get objects
  $res = $query->execute(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Xippo's answer, I have noticed the following:

Using `$query->statement()` leads to Extbase not returning the correct result count. I have found the solution to this problem here:
https://gist.github.com/smichaelsen/2bfdfb872d04a0776f01